# How to prove equality between two supremums?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, supremum-and-infimum

$if\ \int_{c_1}^{c_2}f(x)dx\ge0 \ for\ all\ c_1,c_2\ that:\ a\le c_1\le c_1\lt b.\\
So,\ if\ we\ define\ F(t)=\int_{a}^{t}f(x)dx,\ so,\ we\ will\ get\ for\ all\ c\in[a,b]\\F(d)=\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx+\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx\ge\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx\\So,\ we\ get\ that\ sup\{\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx:[c,d]\subset[a,b)\}=sup\{F(t):t\in[a,b)\}$

How to prove that both sup are indeed the same?
The right supremum is indeed the bigger one, but how can I show that he is the smallest compared to all other upper limits of the left expression?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $\beta=sup\{\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx:[c,d]\subset[a,b)\}$ and $\alpha=sup\{F(t):t\in[a,b)\}$. Assume $\beta<\alpha$, then $\delta=\alpha-\beta>0$. By the definition of supremum, we can find $t\in[a,b)$ s.t. $F(t)>\alpha-\frac{\delta}{2}$. Since $[a,t]\subset[a,b), F(t)\in \{\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx:[c,d]\subset[a,b)\}$, so $\beta\ge F(t)>\alpha-\frac{\delta}{2}$. Thus $\frac{\delta}{2}>\alpha-\beta=\delta$ and we have a contradiction. Therefore $\beta\ge\alpha$.

- Remark: I implicitly assumed that $\alpha<\infty$. If
  $\alpha=\infty$, then there is a sequience $\{F(t_n)\}$ s.t.
  $F(t_n)\rightarrow\infty$. Since each
  $F(t_n)\in\{\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx:[c,d]\subset[a,b)\}$, $\beta=\infty$
  as well.

Comment: Actually, since $F(t)\in \{\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx:[c,d]\subset[a,b)\}$ for every $t\in[a,b)$, we have $\{F(t):t\in[a,b)\}\subset\{\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx:[c,d]\subset[a,b)\}$, so $\beta\ge\alpha$ trivially.